# Optional rewrite rule for AST in ANTLR

Tags: antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a problem while building AST in ANTLR (I'm using ANTLR 3.2, ANTLRWorks 1.4).

This is my grammar:

```
classDeclaration
    :
    (
        'class' n=IDENTIFIER ('extends' e=IDENTIFIER)?
        '{'
        …
        '}'
    )
        -> ^(CLASSDECLARATION ^(NAME $n) ^(EXTENDS $e)
;
```

The problem occurs with optional part of the class — `('extends' e=IDENTIFIER)?`.

So the grammar works good with this class declaration:

```
class Test1 extends AbstractTest1 {
…
}
```

And fails when I exclude `extends` part, as follows:

```
class Test2 {
…
}
```

ANTLR just stops before this fragment and gives this exception in console:
`javax.swing.text.BadLocationException: Position not represented by view`

How can I point to ANTLR to handle rewrite rule `^(EXTENDS $e)` as optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the problem solved. Nothing tricky, just had to use common RegExp syntax:

```
^(EXTENDS $e)?
```